# Artifacts for failed builds in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to know how to generate artifacts for failed builds in gitlab continuous integration, to view the html report generated by the build.

I tried like this:

```
 artifacts:
    when: on_failure
      paths:
        - SmokeTestResults/
        - package.json
```

but it does not work unfortunately. I am using Gitlab 8.11.4 community edition.

Answer (score 83):

Using `when: on_failure` will upload the artifact *only* when there is a failure.

To always upload the artifact *despite* a failure, use `when: always`.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/index.html#artifactswhen

Answer (score 31):

When, path, and the files should all be at the same level

```
artifacts:
  when: on_failure
  paths:
  - SmokeTestResults/
  - package.json
```